# How to get the first folder not the root?

Tags: c#

If the path in `textBoxPath` for example is: `d:\test1\test2`. I want to get the path: `d:\\test1` but the code below gets me `d:\\`

```cs
var root = Path.GetPathRoot(textBoxPath.Text);
```

Comment: This is unrelated to WinForms, btw. You'd have the same issue in a console app.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on further requirements, there are two options I came up with.

Option 1: `DirectoryInfo.Parent`

```cs
var path = "d:\\test1\\test2";
var directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);
var parentDirectoryInfo = directoryInfo.Parent;
```

Option 2: `Path.GetFullPath(string, string)`

```cs
var path = Path.GetFullPath("../", "d:\\test1\\test2");
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the input in your `textBoxPath` variable is dynamic and you need to get the last not-root directory you can do this:

```cs
var dir = Directory.CreateDirectory(textBoxPath.Text)!;

while (dir.Parent?.FullName != dir.Root.FullName)
{
    dir = dir.Parent;
}

Console.WriteLine(dir); // Will print 'd:\test1' in your scenario.
```

In other words, you are getting the parent directory of the current one as long as it's not the root of the whole path.